# How to Repair Ubuntu boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-7, boot

I have hard disk contain Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11 so I cloned it to new one but when I replaced it no OS working just dell mark appearing then restart by itself.
In the past started up by Ubuntu menu to select Windows or Ubuntu so now how can I fix Ubuntu boot to avoid reinstall everything.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your BIOS doesn't see the disk at all. Can you check that in the BIOS POST phase the hard disk is actually recognized?

Comment: no it recognized even I can see the size of new hard disk by the way when I plugged the old hard disk it's works! so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are booting from the correct device. If its a grub issue, you can use an ubuntu CD to recover it.